# Browser storage import json file

Tags: sqlite, ionic3

I work on a Ionic v3 App;

And for my database I use SQLite, on init I import json file for create the datatable with SQLitePorter.

Is it possible to import this json files to the Browser storage for testing with "ionic serve"?

Answer (score 0):

If the version of sqlite3 you're using has the [JSON1](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html) extension compiled in, it's easy to turn JSON into a table.

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE people(name TEXT, age INTEGER);
INSERT INTO people(name, age)
  SELECT json_extract(json_each.value, '$.name'), json_extract(json_each.value, '$.age')
  FROM json_each('[{"name":"Bob","age":25},{"name":"Hilda","age":50}]');
```

(In a program, you'd have the insert as a prepared statement with the argument to `json_each()` a placeholder that you bind to the contents of your json file. From a sqlite shell, there's the [readfile()](https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html#file_i_o_functions) function.)

Comment: Hmm sorry, I may have forgotten details. My JSON files create tables and don't insert data.